# Ruby: Undefined Method `<'

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

As a way to learn the ins and outs of ruby, I decided to make a (relatively simple) text-based RPG. Everything so far has gone well, except recently I've hit a roadblock that I haven't seen before.

*My goal is: if any stat (str, def, agi, man) is < 0, I want to make it = 0. For some reason though, ruby doesn't seem to like the `<'.*

**Here's the code ruby hangs up on:**

```
def self.compile
@str = ProfileData.load['g_str']
@def = ProfileData.load['g_def']
@agi = ProfileData.load['g_agi']
@man = ProfileData.load['g_man']
@smin = 1
@dmin = 1
@amin = 1
@mmin = 1
if @str < @smin
  @str = 0
end
if @def < @dmin
  @def = 0
end
if @agi < @amin
  @agi = 0
end
if @man < @mmin
  @man = 0
end
@str.round!
@def.round!
@agi.round!
@man.round!
d = YAML::load_file('./profile')
d['mstr'] = @str
File.open('./profile', 'w') {|f| f.write d.to_yaml}
d = YAML::load_file('./profile')
d['mdef'] = @def
File.open('./profile', 'w') {|f| f.write d.to_yaml}
d = YAML::load_file('./profile')
d['magi'] = @agi
File.open('./profile', 'w') {|f| f.write d.to_yaml}
d = YAML::load_file('./profile')
d['mman'] = @man
File.open('./profile', 'w') {|f| f.write d.to_yaml}
```

end

**Now when I run through my program, I get this error code when it finally runs "compile":**

```
start.rb:734:in `compile': undefined method `<' for []:Array (NoMethodError)
```

And that's it. Have any clue what's happened or how I can fix it? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like your loading code `@str = ProfileData.load['g_str']` is returning an array rather than in individual value so it can't be used in a `<` comparison.

Comment: Where you wrote `if @def < @dmin`, did you mean `if @ddef…`? Because you named the variable `@ddef`.

Comment: @SebastianMotraghi - thanks for catching that. That was accidentally left over from trying to fix the problem previously. I forgot to remove the extra d.

Answer (score 1):

It means your variables (at leas one per compared pair) is of `Array` type.

Check what each of these

```
@str = ProfileData.load['g_str']
@ddef = ProfileData.load['g_def']
@agi = ProfileData.load['g_agi']
@man = ProfileData.load['g_man']
```

returns and make sure it is [Comparable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Comparable.html) (integers, for example).

Comment: That's good to at least understand what the error means - thank you!
I added a quick option in the beginning menu to pull the values of the above mentioned - they all load, and are all numbers.

Comment: @ChristopherHarlan you can use `is_a?(Comparable)` to check the general type of each of aformentioned

Comment: Hey Andrey - thanks for the response. Sadly, I have no idea how to do what you're suggesting. Where should I put '.is_a?()' after, and what should I be looking for?

Answer (score 1):

The load method seems to assume that would be a collection of variables, even you having just one.

If you grant to be always one, select just the first and as it may be a string you should make it a int.

```
@str = ProfileData.load['g_str'].first.to_i
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion (adding the .first.to_i) and it works to a degree - the first time around. For some reason, it takes all the values (for example, ['str'] is set to 14) and sets them to zero - unsure how. Then the next time I update the stats, I end up with: 


'start.rb:725:in `compile': undefined method `first' for 15:Fixnum (NoMethodError)'

Comment: The first time you got something like an empty string.  Than, the second time you got already a number.  Did you checked the file after and before saving? Something has changed?

Comment: Nothing has changed - the only part changing is the value of 'g_str', as it's based from a random number. By looking at the file that hosts 'g_str' (through YAML, in the same directory), the number is already there.
The number has always been there but the above method can't seem to find it and/or tell that it's a number.

Comment: You said in other comment that they are always numbers, in this case .first doesn't makes sense, even .to_i.  Now, why you got an array the first time, than numbers the second time its very weird.  Maybe is the way you are saving.  Try file = File.open(...)
file.write d.to_yaml
file.close()

Comment: When I comment '.first.to_i' and all the < lines, everything works fine - the numbers even show up. But when I try to make sure nothing gets below 0 (at times, depending on luck and choices made in character creation, I've had the stats in the negatives), then I start to get the errors. The way it's saved tot he file works fine.

Comment: I cannot figure out why.  At each iteration get the class of each one.
puts @str.class

Comment: I tried what you advised, and did `puts "This is str: #{@str}"` right after the initial loading from ProfileData.load['g_str']. The answer came up as: `This is str: []`.

Comment: Now we know, the load method isn't right, its returning and empty array.  Are you sure the file has some value in the first iteration?  May be that.  I would like to suggest to you use json instead.
hero = {}
hero[:g_str] = random number
hero[:g_des] = another random number
...
file = File.new "yourfilename.txt", "w" (w for writing)
file << hero.to_json
and load the as json